# Can a Dishwasher that automatically opens the door damage my kitchen cabinets?

Tags: dishwasher

Can a Dishwasher that automatically opens the door when finishing the cycle (to let steam out for better drying performance) cause damage to the kitchen cabinets?
I'm worried since it doesn't open the door entirely - just a small amount to create a hatch, can this cause condensation on the lower part of the worktop and damage the cabinets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can deterioration of chipboard damaged by steam be arrested?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/95062/can-deterioration-of-chipboard-damaged-by-steam-be-arrested)

Comment: Why not just turn off that "feature" ?  (I do hope that's an option!)

Comment: I'm curious - do you have a model number for the dishwasher?  I'd like to know more about this "feature".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your countertop, especially the lip that overhangs the dishwasher, is constructed with particle board, you can expect damage. The particle board will suck up any and all moisture coming out of the dishwasher. I have heard that even granite tops can get discolored from the steam you're referring to.

You can coat the bottom of a particle board top with some exterior wood glue or silicone sealer to prevent the moisture from being absorbed. If it's granite, get a stone sealer and just apply to the bottom part of the lip.

Comment: My dishwasher came with a self sticking foil tape for the underside of the counter top.